# Customize widget's ID attribute in Twig

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to customize HTML 'id' attribute in Twig when rendering a widget with
`{{ form_widget(form.NAME_OF_THE_FIELD) }}` ?

Passing `{'attr': {'id': 'SOMETHING'}}` doesn't work...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you try: `{{ form_widget(form.title, { 'id': 'my_custom_id' }) }}`?

If this still doesn't work, you could also rely on form customization to handle it. But this could be overkill and may not be the best idea. Check the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) on form theming for more info.

As I said, maybe there is better way but this is only what I can propose you for now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it works :) Don't know why I didn't thought of it before, probably because passing `array('id' => 'something')` in the FormBuilder resulted in exception being thrown. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5):

```
{{ form_widget(form.title, { 'attr': {'id': 'my_id'} }) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

I have used it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can help for googlers but you also can specify the prefix of the attribut in the formType

```
public function getName()
{
   return 'vendor_testbundle_sickness';
}
```

your attribute will have the folowing id :

```
vendor_testbundle_sickness_SOMETHING
```